Is there a practical difference between an IDP and a translation for countries that sign the Vienna convention?
I often read advice that a certain country requires tourists to carry an IDP. However, when I check the details further, the IDP is usually only required for licenses that doesn't comply with the Vienna convention, are not written in Latin chars, or are not written in a certain language (or even the older Geneva convention, usually in EU countries).

International Driving Permits are governed by three international
conventions: the 1926 Paris International Convention relative to Motor
Traffic, the 1949 Geneva Convention on Road Traffic, and the 1968
Vienna Convention on Road Traffic.

Last time I got an IDP it looked almost exactly like my driver license itself, with the addition of French, Arab and maybe another translation (besides Spanish and English already included in my original driver license).
So what is the difference besides the additional languages? (And the shorter expiration date?)

or have different drivers classes. That is actually the main propose of an IDP. A Police official must be able to determine if you are licensed to drive the vehicle if you ate involved in a accident.

Not all countries issue driving licenses that are in the format(s) prescribed by the Conventions. In that case you need an IDP. The low and latch if the versions of the specific convention the country of the driver and the visited country signed may also be another reason one is needed.

Japan is a notable example where it matters: they only recognize IDPs from countries that are signatories of the Geneva (1949) convention, plus a few European countries with special agreements.  If you have a Vienna (1968) IDP, you're out of luck, even with a translation.
Wikipedia has a full list of who recognizes what:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit#Countries_and_jurisdictions_that_recognize_IDP

I understand that in this case even the IDP doesn't work? Then there's no difference in having one?

There is no one "the IDP", there are multiple standards. Japan accepts only 1-year Geneva IDPs, which are weird retro cardboard pamphlets that look like they escaped from a WW2 refugee camp, but are easily obtained in countries like Australia that are also Geneva signatories.  If your IDP looks like a modern credit card sized driver's license, it's not a Geneva IDP.
